# Automatically size image components in React Native

Tags: image, react-native

I want to set the width of an `Image` component to be 100% of my container's width and the height to be set according to the result width value and image's aspect ratio.

My container has some padding, which means that `Dimensions.get('window').width` is not useful to me since it does not gives me the value that results from image's width being set to 100%. Other scenarios also can't afford the Dimensions API as a acceptable solution.

Here's an code example:

```js
<View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  }}>
  <Image
    style={{
      flex: 1, // Not what I want => just so I can see the image
      width: '100%',
      // height: 'auto', // The behavior that I want
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/000000',
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Result:

[image: app]

The red background serves just to visualize that the `Image` component.

Using `onLayout` prop I can get the runtime value of the resulting width, and with the aid of the Image API i could calculate the desired height. The problem with that is that React Native will first render a 0 height component and just after that `onLayout` seems to be resolved, and that makes sense.

So?

- Is there a way to get before hand the width value of a image component such as this (declared using relative width)?
- Is automatically setting image height even possible in React Native? If so, how?

Notes:
- In the image [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#why-not-automatically-size-everything) of React Native there is an explanation of why they chose not to size image components automatically by default.
- At least in this case, Parent `onLayout` is resolved after its children.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground, can you try this

Answer (score 3):

In your componentDidMount you could calculate the image metrics, and then use that height and width to calculate the aspectRatio.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   Image.getSize(YourUri, (width, height) => {
      this.setState({width, height});
    });
}
```

In your image you will add the styles like this:

```
  <Image
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      aspectRatio: this.state.height !== null ? this.state.width / this.state.height : 1
    }}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x400/000000',
    }}
  />
```

As stated in React native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props):

> Aspect ratio controls the size of the undefined dimension of a node.
>   Aspect ratio is a non-standard property only available in React Native
>   and not CSS.
>
> -On a node with a set width/height aspect ratio controls the size of the unset dimension
>
> -On a node with a set flex basis aspect ratio controls the size of the node in the cross axis if unset
>
> -On a node with a measure function aspect ratio works as though the measure function measures the flex basis
>
> -On a node with flex grow/shrink aspect ratio controls the size of the node in the cross axis if unset

Aspect ratio takes min/max dimensions into account